# how do I invoke a post-back from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, postback, code-behind

I am having an issue with my usercontrol being loaded too late in the "post back timeline", because they are being loaded in as a result of a custom event.

As a result the button click events on this usercontrol don't fire on the first click (the entire post-back occurs only the event-handlers for the click don't get raised). On the second click (and hence second post-back), however, the event-handlers work fine.

How can I invoke a second post-back automatically right after one has just finished? So my usercontrol gets loaded correctly.

Default Page

```
public interface IEventProvider
{
    void TriggerEvent(String path);
}


public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IEventProvider
{
    private string LastLoadedControl
    {
        get
        {
            return Session[Paths.CURRENTCTRL] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            Session[Paths.CURRENTCTRL] = value;
        }
    }

    private void LoadUserControl()
    {
        string controlPath = LastLoadedControl;

        ContentPlaceholder.Controls.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controlPath))
            controlPath = Utils.Paths.USERCTRL_BASE + "Main.ascx";

        Control uc = Page.LoadControl(controlPath);
        ContentPlaceholder.Controls.Add(uc);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadUserControl();
    }

    public void TriggerEvent(String path)
    {
        if (path.Equals("logout"))
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Session.Abandon();
            LastLoadedControl = null;
        }
        else LastLoadedControl = Paths.USERCTRL_BASE + path + ".ascx";
        LoadUserControl();
    }
}
```

Usercontrol code

```
protected void profileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Utils.Events.triggerRedirectPage(this.Page, "Login");
    }
```

events code

```
 public static void triggerRedirectPage(Page p, String path)
    {
        IEventProvider eventProvider = p as IEventProvider;
        if (eventProvider != null)
            eventProvider.TriggerEvent(path);
    }
```

Comment: I think you're trying to fix the symptoms of bugged code rather than fixing the bugged code. You never want to have a double-postback. If your events aren't hooked up the first time then fix that.

Comment: I don't know how to sort out the timings so the usercontrol gets fully loaded. Events always trigger last, which results in the usercontrol being loaded too late in the operation. How can the main page detect a button click in a usercontrol and then load in another usercontrol as a result of that early enough for it to be fully loaded.

Comment: You can use this code in your User Control to invoke a method on the parent: `this.Page.GetType().InvokeMember("MyMethodName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this.Page, new object[] { });` You're not relying on events then.

Comment: Can you include arguments in that technique?

Comment: Yup, the last param `new object[] { }` is for the arguments

Comment: tried that too. still too late in the queue, the usercontrol is still not loaded soon enough :/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button (or another control) with `AllowPostBack=true` then trigger click event on this button.

Comment: trigger using javascript? could I also inject a __dopostback using register startup script?